# C++ Print out "not found" message when searching a vector only once

Tags: c++, vector

here is a little snippet of my code where I am stuck. I want the code to keep prompting the user to search for a name, even when found. So breaks in my code won't work. My code is flawed because every time the for loop reaches one less my vector size it prints out "name not found!"
Which is what I told it, but I just can't figure out a way to fix this. I have found other posts on stack and tried them in my code but they are not working.

```
do
{
    cout <<"Enter name for search: ";
    cin >> name;

    for (int i = 0; i < pvector.size(); i++)
    {
        if (pvector[i]->fName == name || pvector[i]->lName == name)
        {
            cout << pvector[i]->fName << " "<< pvector[i] ->lName <<" "<<"username:"<< pvector[i]->userName <<" "<<"password:" << pvector[i]->pword <<endl;
        }else if(i == pvector.size()-1)
        {
            cout << name <<" "<<"not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
} while (cin.good());
```

Comment: Nevermind, I was reading 'pvector' as 'pointer to a vector' not 'vector of pointers to structs' (Probably named 'Profile' based off OPs previous posts.)

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This can be easily solved by using a debugger.

Comment: ^ yes, and 'cin.good()' is not a good sentinel value for the do-while, though 'name' might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a break once you've find a match, this works on my side:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> pvector;
    pvector.push_back("Steve");
    pvector.push_back("Jhon");
    pvector.push_back("Michael");

    char name[256];

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter name for search: ";
        cin >> name;

        for (int i = 0; i < pvector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (pvector[i] == name)
            {
                cout << pvector[i] << " found" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (i == pvector.size() - 1)
            {
                cout << name << " " << "not found!" << endl;
            }
        }
    } while (cin.good());
}
```

Comment: This code worked but I ran into one problem, if I have multiple names and want to print them out, it only prints out the first one it finds. I assume this is because of the break. How would I be able to print out all the names found in the vector?

Comment: Just keep a counter of the number of time the name is found. Only output the "Not found" if the counter is still at 0 when reaching the end of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

after the name was found in your pvector, you should break the current for loop, that means the following code

```
cout << "Enter name for search: ";
cin >> name;

for (int i = 0; i < pvector.size(); i++)
{
    if (pvector[i]->fName == name || pvector[i]->lName == name)
    {
        cout << pvector[i]->fName << " "<< pvector[i] ->lName <<" "<<"username:"<< pvector[i]->userName <<" "<<"password:" << pvector[i]->pword <<endl;
        break; // add a break here
    }
    else if(i == pvector.size()-1)
    {
        cout << name <<" "<<"not found!" << endl;
    }
}
```

the break added above will only break the current `for` loop and continues the rest `do ... while` loop